# How to get parent object from child one to many in Spring Data jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Employee extends AuditModel implements Serializable {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "employee_generator", sequenceName = "employee_seq", allocationSize = 50)
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    String lastName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Task> tasks;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Task implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Task() {
        super();
    }

    public Task(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    // details
    // type, priority, label, status

    // description

    // customer address
    // state, city, state

    // people
    // assignee, reporter

    // dates
    // created, updated

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "task_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="task_generator", sequenceName = "task_seq", allocationSize=50)
    @Column(name = "TASK_ID")
    long taskId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    Employee employee;

}
```

when I get from employee -> task. I am getting an employee object and list of tasks.w
ex:

```
{

"employeeId":1,

"tasks":[
{
"taskId":1,
"title":"first task"
}

]
}

}
```

Now the problem I want to get from Task(child) -> employee(parent). I am not getting employee object because I put @JsonIgnore annotation. If I remove the `@JsonIgnore` I get an infinite loop. Now I want to take employee object from task object, how can I do that?

Comment: you should avoid passing entity object to UI, can you try creating an equivalent VO and populate same from entity and try

Comment: I need employee object I want to show employee name in UI. could you please tell me ?

Comment: on first look, nothing seems wrong in your program, even if you try to print employee using system.out.print, you would be getting it, please confirm

Comment: when i tried in postman rest client i am not getting

Comment: not in postman, in your java code, let say in RestController, (just want to confirm)

Comment: I am getting null value. please tell me a solution to it

Comment: not getting null values ?

Comment: oh, sorry i am getting null ex: employee= null null pointer exception throws

Comment: ok, let me copy your code and run it

Comment: ok. please do it

Comment: just ran it, without any issue

Comment: did you get employee object when you take a task findByTaskId(taskId);

Comment: I used findAll , you can access code here https://github.com/KoolShailesh/jpa-with-database

Comment: i will test and let you know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Comment: With reference to the above, refer to this answer rather than the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18288939/1356423

Comment: @shailesh i tried was not working can you send me json object?

Comment: I have updated my project,  on latest project I get this {"taskId":8,"description":"new Task","employee":{"employeeId":4,"firstName":"Shailesh","lastName":"Chandra","tasks":null} when I use **curl http://localhost:8080/employee/task/8**

Comment: I think you should also follow @AlanHay suggestion, which might solve your problem

Comment: i am not clear with your project. employee has list of tasks. task has an employee.
employee ex : { id: 1, tasks:[{},[]]},  and task ex : {taskId:1, employee:{employeeId:1}}. I need like this.